# HttpWebRequest WebProxy problem - The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: .net, proxy, httpwebrequest, webproxy

I'm trying to make a HTTP request through an open SOCKS5 proxy. I have verified that the proxy works by setting it as a proxy for Firefox before setting it as the proxy in my C#.Net application by setting `request.Proxy = new WebProxy(ip, port);`

However, on attempting to run the application and make my request I get an exception - *System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.*

I'm unsure what is causing this - the proxy seems to be open and working fine. I've also tried this with other seemingly working proxies and get the same exception. Any clues as to why this is happening and how I can go about rectifying it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `WebProxy` class does not support Socks proxies which is exactly what I was trying to use. How useful!

The question now becomes - How to use a [Socks Proxy for HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855726/socks-proxy-for-httpwebrequest) ?!

Answer (score 1):

You can not. 
check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366665/squid-proxy-reset-connection-immediately