# Socks Proxy for HttpWebRequest

Tags: .net, proxy, httpwebrequest, socks

According to my research whilst trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855137/httpwebrequest-webproxy-problem-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly) problem, it turns out that the .Net WebProxy class does not support Socks proxies - a tad annoying. I also can't seem to find any code or information which explains how to implement Socks 4/5 support via a class which can easily be used with HttpWebRequest (the Proxy property, to be exact).

I've found limited information via google on how I could do this. [One suggestion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/00141a94-a127-46e5-9c92-fe8d106efb56) involves changing internet explorer proxy settings - something I'd rather not do.

Does anyone know of anything which could do the job or have any suggestions? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried numerous .Net libraries which claimed to support Socks4/5 but found many of them just did not work or would error trying to connect to proxies I knew were functioning.

I've ended up using [Chilkat Software's Sock/SSL component](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/socket-features.asp) which seems to work well for me even if I do have to manually construct the HTTP requests instead of using HttpWebRequest as I would have liked.

- Update note: Chilkat.Http (similar to the HttpWebRequest class) does inherently have support for SOCKS proxies. So don't spend time trying to code your own HTTP requests as I did; just use the `Chilkat.Http.SocksHostname`, `Chilkat.Http.SocksPort` and `Chilkat.Http.SocksVersion` properties.

Comment: Chilkat does now inherently support SOCKS. `Chilkat.Http.SocksVersion`, `Chilkat.Http.SocksHostname`, `Chilkat.Http.SocksPort`. Configuring those properties will force the HTTP connections to utilize SOCKS. Chilkat API reference: [link](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csHttpRef.html)

Answer (score 2):

Changing IE's proxy settings won't help you at all-- the other poster was just observing that it works for IE. Because the .NET Framework doesn't support SOCKS, you'd have to write your own CERN-Proxy to SOCKS-Proxy converter, such that .NET talks to the CERN proxy (the type it supports) and your code converts that to a SOCKS proxy call.

FWIW, this is something I'm presently looking to add to FiddlerCore (www.fiddler2.com/core) because I already have almost all of the code. The only thing I really need is a SOCKSv4a proxy to test against.

Comment: The suggestion that got me to that page was to change the IE proxy and then use the WebProxy.DefaultProxy property - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/982bef6c-b9a4-4c0d-b7d5-0c64df9f610a. I'm just surprised that I can't find any class/library to implement this easily via code - it seems like such an obvious thing to want to do. Would be great if you did implement it - I'll keep an eye on the FiddlerCore project.

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 6, socks proxies can be used natively with `HttpClient`. See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17740) issue on GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) or same to create http proxy gateway to your socks.

Add this to main config to chain Privoxy and socks:

`forward-socks5   /               proxy_host:port .`

And something like that to enable direct access to your local network:

`forward         192.168.*.*/     .
forward            10.*.*.*/     .
forward           127.*.*.*/     .`