# Make an HTTP request through a SOCKS proxy

Tags: c#, socks

How can I make an HTTP request through a SOCKS/SOCKS5 proxy? It seems that `HttpWebRequest` only supports an HTTP proxy, without support for SOCKS5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socks Proxy for HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855726/socks-proxy-for-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 2):

I think this post might be really helpfull to you. The anwser states why certain .NET classses are not capable of using a socks5 proxy directly and explains how to write client code using the `WebClient` and `HTTPWebRequest` classes.

[use-webclient-with-socks-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122369/use-webclient-with-socks-proxy)

This one might be helpful as well since it shows how to use a third party .NET library offering the functionality to talk to socks5 proxies.

[socks-proxy-for-httpwebrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855726/socks-proxy-for-httpwebrequest)

Comment: Can you give me any other solution?

Comment: I extended my post. Try approach #2 (Third party .NET).

Comment: I will try it and ask you later. Thank you very much